# How can I keep the form when I use Expand[2a+3b]^5 and apply to all elements of a list?

Tags: output-formatting, latex

I want to keep the form of the expression `(2a + 3b)^5`. I tried

```
myex = Expand[(x + y)^5];
ReplaceAll[myex, {x -> 2 a, y -> 3 b}]
```

I get

> 32 a^5 + 240 a^4 b + 720 a^3 b^2 + 1080 a^2 b^3 + 810 a b^4 + 243 b^5

How can I get the result like this?

> (2a + 3b)^5 = (2 a)^5 + 5 (2 a)^4 (3 b) + 10 (2 a)^3 (3 b)^2 + 10 (2 a)^2 (3 b)^3 + 5 (2 a) (3 b)^4 + (3 b)^5 = 32 a^5 + 240 a^4 b + 720 a^3 b^2 + 1080 a^2 b^3 + 810 a b^4 + 243 b^5

I have a list

```
list={{(2x-y)^5}, {(3 u + 2v)^5},{(1/2 a + Sqrt[2] b)^5};
```

How can I  get

{{(2x-y)^5 = (2 x)^5 + 5 (2 x)^4 (-y) + 10 (2 x)^3 (-y)^2 + 10 (2 x)^2 (-y)^3 + 5 (2 x) (-y)^4 + (-y)^5=32 x^5 - 80 x^4 y + 80 x^3 y^2 - 40 x^2 y^3 + 10 x y^4 - y^5},{(3u + 2v)^5 = (3 u)^5 + 5 (3 u)^4 (2 v) + 10 (3 u)^3 (2 v)^2 + 10 (3 u)^2 (2 v)^3 + 5 (3 u) (2 v)^4 + (2 v)^5 = 243 u^5 + 810 u^4 v + 1080 u^3 v^2 + 720 u^2 v^3 + 240 u v^4 + 32 v^5},{(1/2a+ Sqrt[2]b)^5 = (1/2 a)^5 + 5 (1/2 a)^4 (Sqrt[2] b) + 10 (1/2 a)^3 (Sqrt[2] b)^2 + 10 (1/2 a)^2 (Sqrt[2] b)^3 + 5 (1/2 a) (Sqrt[2] b)^4 + (Sqrt[2] b)^5 = a^5/32 + (5 a^4 b)/(8 Sqrt[2]) + (5 a^3 b^2)/2 + 5 Sqrt[2] a^2 b^3 + 10 a b^4 + 4 Sqrt[2] b^5}}

Comment: what do you mean by **get the text file of result** ? what does text file doing here? If you want to generate Latex file then you can do this easily also. See `TeXForm` command and then save everything to plain text .tex file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of many

```
myex = (x + y)^5
e = myex /. {x -> HoldForm[2  a], y -> HoldForm[3  b]}
Expand[e]
Expand@ReleaseHold[e]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For formatting, you could use `Row`

```
 Row[{e, " = ", Expand[e], " = ", Expand@ReleaseHold[e]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> How about my list?

You could make the above code into the function and Map it to the list. This is the functional way of doing things

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, y];
list = {(2 x - y)^5, (3 x - 2)^5};
convert[expr_, x_, y_, xrep_, yrep_] := Module[{e},
  e = expr /. {x -> HoldForm[xrep], y -> HoldForm[yrep]};
  Row[{e, " = ", Expand[e], " = ", Expand@ReleaseHold[e]}]
  ]
```

Now do

```
convert[#, x, y, 2*a, 2*b] & /@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For formatting, it depends what is your target. I'd generate Latex if I was you, but that is a side issue. Just keep the final representation separate from the computation part.

### Update for updated question

Try this version

```
convert[expr_] := Module[{e, n, body, any, vars, v1, v2},
   n = expr /. any_^n_. :> n;
   body = expr /. any_^n_. :> any;
   vars = Variables[body];
   v1 = HoldForm[v1] /. v1 :> With[{eval = Select[body, FreeQ[vars[[2]]]]}, eval /; True];
   v2 = HoldForm[v2] /. v2 :> With[{eval = Select[body, FreeQ[vars[[1]]]]}, eval /; True];
   e = (v1 + v2)^n;
   Row[{expr, " = ", Expand[e], " = ", Expand@ReleaseHold[e]}]
   ];
list = {(2 x - y)^5, (3  u + 2 v)^5, (1/2  a + Sqrt[2]  b)^5};
convert[#] & /@ list
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter it is very hard to understand and follow what you are asking. Can you be clear in your post what is the input? I used same list you showed and replacement you showed. You can change these as needed?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: When I Copy as LaTex, the result changes the form.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter yes, sometimes TeXForm changes the expression layout. This is just how TeXForm is really, nothing one can really do about it. But maybe you can post separate question giving the input and showing the latex output and explain what you want it to be, may be someone will have an idea.  Note that TeXForm is based on TraditionalForm and not on InputForm.